# How to increase range Of Ad-hoc network using Rasberry Pi 3?

Tags: routing, ad-hoc-network, raspbian

I am working on MANET using rasberry pi 3 (micro-controller), I want to make 3 rasberry pi as a router and each of three not in range with them, now if I shuffle these 3 rasberry pi they dont change topology. Now my question is how I can increase range of adhoc network using AODV routing protocol?

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how I can increase range of adhoc network using AODV routing protocol?

Short answer: you can't.

The [Ad hoc On-Demand Distance Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_On-Demand_Distance_Vector_Routing) routing protocol is just that, a protocol. It doesn't allow more/less dB gain on your antenna.

From the [AODV protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3561.txt) text:

> The Ad hoc On-Demand Distance Vector (AODV) routing protocol is
>      intended for use by mobile nodes in an ad hoc network.  It offers
>      quick adaptation to dynamic link conditions, low processing and
>      memory overhead, low network utilization, and determines unicast
>      routes to destinations within the ad hoc network.  It uses
>      destination sequence numbers to ensure loop freedom at all times
>      (even in the face of anomalous delivery of routing control messages),
>      avoiding problems (such as "counting to infinity") associated with
>      classical distance vector protocols.

In other words, the AODV would allow your 3 RPi's to communicate to any one connected to the MANET which path to take for further communications. It wouldn't increase the connectable range of the devices; on the contrary, one of the points of the AODV protocol is in the event one of your RPi's drops out of range, the other 2 will know how to handle it.

If you want to increase the range of the individual RPi's you'll need more powerful/better antenna's. You can do a lot with software, unfortunately breaking the laws of physics is not one of them yet.

Hope that can add some clarity.

Comment: Thanks for giving more clear picture to my project and your answer helps me alot in practical implementation.

Comment: Can you tell me about code in C++ or python for AdHoc network or any link you have for MANET coding in Rasberry pi3..